# Rails initialize variables in server startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization

I want to initialize a variable in rails and use it in a controller's action, but the variable should have a fixed value when the server starts. I have tried defining it inside a controller's action and it get's the same initialized value for every request. For example, i want to initialize a date.now and have the same date after 15 days also.

**Update**
I am implementing a coming soon page in which a timer is shown 15 days from now. If i implement it in a action inside a controller, it shows new date every time the action is invoked.

Please Help

Comment: Can you elaborate what is " a date.now and have the same date after 15 days also." what it's usage?

Comment: I am trying to implement a coming soon page in which i want to have a date of today and show the timer for 15 days more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a CONSTANT in rails then you can simply put it into the `initializer` file. For eg, create a file name `constants.rb` inside `initializer`:

```
#config/initializers/constants.rb 
TEST_VALUE = 10
```

And to access this CONSTANT from your controller, just call for `TEST_VALUE`. for eg,

```
#controllers_path/some_controller.rb
.....
def some_def
    @value = TEST_VALUE # this will be enough to fetch the constants.
end
```

But, make sure you restart your server after changing the `intializer`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to create a [constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28programming%29), which is basically a variable which doesn't change its value

You'd typically set these with [initializers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/Rails/Initializer.html):

```
#config/initializers/your_initializer.rb
YOUR_CONSTANT = your_date
```

To maintain a persistent date, you'll have to give some more context on what you're using it for. It will be difficult to create this each time Rails loads (how to know which `Time.now` to use), so giving us more info will be a good help

Comment: How can i access 'YOUR_CONSTANT' variable in my controller or views? Please provide some explanation.

Comment: See my answer for your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an opposite approach. Assuming you should know the date when the new feature comes (for example `2014-04-04 18:00`) you can just find a number of seconds left till the target date:

```
@seconds_left = Time.parse('2014-04-04 18:00').to_i - Time.now.to_i
```

then pass it to client side and implement a timer. So you'll just need to store a string representation of a target date.

Obvious disadvantage of this approach is that you should adjust that target time each time you want to introduce a new feature.